# how to suggest friends in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to suggest some friends randomly to users, no matter if there is any mutual friends between suggestion and current session_user.

Here is what i have tried :

```
$sess = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['user_id']));

$qet = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user.id AS id, user.name AS name, user.u_name AS u_name, user.profile_pic AS profile_pic

FROM user INNER JOIN user_friend ON (user.id = user_friend.add_by_id) OR (user.id = user_friend.add_to_id) 

WHERE (user_friend.add_to_id != '$sess' or user_friend.add_by_id != '$sess') AND (user.id != '$sess') 

ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

My table structure :

user_friend

> 1. id
> 2. add_by_id
> 3. add_to_id
> 4. added_on
> 5. accepted

user

> 1. id
> 2. name
> 3. u_name
> 4. profile_pic
> 5. email
> 6. password
> 7. gender

I am not getting the proper results, it suggests me those friends also who are already friend with me(current session_user).

Comment: Did you try excluding the list of already friends?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` isn't intended to escape query parameters.

Comment: @PraveenKumar no bhai, can you explain it more on how to do it, please ? because i am in 12th now and i am new in programming and i have learned it by my ownself

Comment: I highly suggest you follow Don't Panic's advice and don't use `htmlspecialchars()`. You use that function to prevent XSS attacks, meaning you use it when you are `echo`ing information to be displayed, not when doing sql queries. To prevent sql injection, Prepared statements and binding parameters are the way to go, and I highly recommend using PDO instead of MySQLi

Answer (score 1):

We can't be sure exactly what is wrong because you are not showing us the structure of tables `user` and table `user_friend`, however, inferring from the information given, your `ON ...` and `WHERE ...` statements are incorrect. I recommend you use the `NOT IN` clause in sql. Something more along these lines **(but probably difference since we don't have the exact format of your tables!)**:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT friends_id FROM user_friends WHERE id = :sess)
```

Again, if you want the exact SQL statement, we need to know the structure of your table. If you update your Question I will happily update my answer :).

**Important:**

Your previous code is unsafe and also not practical. You are using `htmlspecialchars()` incorrectly, and to prevent sql injection the proper way would be to use prepared statements and parameter binding. Here is example of how that is done with MySQL (PDO) (the prefered method):

```
$sess =  $_SESSION['user_id'];

$sql = 
"SELECT 
    user.id AS id, 
    user.name AS name, 
    user.u_name AS u_name, 
    user.profile_pic AS profile_pic
FROM 
    user 
INNER JOIN 
    user_friend 
ON (user.id = user_friend.add_by_id) OR (user.id = user_friend.add_to_id)  
WHERE 
    (user_friend.add_to_id != :sess or user_friend.add_by_id != :sess)
    AND (user.id != :sess) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);      //preparing the statement
$stmt->bindParam(':sess', $sess);  //binding the parameter
$stmt->execute();
```

Later when you decide to output your selected data, you should then use `htmlspecialchars()` like so:

```
echo "Friends: ".htmlspecialchars($data)."<br>";
```

Comment: thank you so much brother, and i have updated it. Can you now answer it please brother ?